# Eigenvalue equation of orbital angular momentum operator $L^2$ and $L_z$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

I am currently working on Gasiorowicz's Quantum Physics. The writer says that since $\mathbf{L}^2$ and $L_z$ commute, we have simultaneous eigenket $|l,m\rangle$, and thus we can write
\begin{align}
\mathbf{L}^2|l,m\rangle & = \hbar l(l+1)|l,m\rangle \\
L_z |l,m\rangle & = \hbar m |l,m\rangle,
\end{align}
without any constraint for $l$ and $m$.

I don't understand why we can write the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{L}^2$ and $L_z$ to depend only on $l$ and $m$, respectively. Shouldn't we set the eigenvalue for $|l,m\rangle$ to be depending on both $l$ and $m$ to consider the most general situation?

Comment: the eigenvalue for L^2 is wrong. You missed a factor of ℏ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\ell,m\rangle$ is an eigenstate for $L^2$ with eigenvalue $\ell(\ell+1)\hbar$, and is also an eigenstate for $L_z$ with eigenvalue $m\hbar$.

There isn't "the eigenvalue for $|\ell,m\rangle$". It is just a state vector.

Comment: Is it okay to set the eigenvalue of L^2 as hbar*l(l+1)? Is it because l(l+1) can cover all real numbers?

Comment: @이승우 There are *proofs* of this sort of thing, e.g. in Dirac's book. The eigenvalues of that operator are of the form *l(l+1)*, which cannot cover all integers, as you may easily check.

Comment: @이승우 We are not "setting" anything. It comes directly from what $L^2$ is and the boundary conditions.

Comment: Oh, I see. They(l and m) are just eigenvalues of different operators, so we denote them with two different letters since they are simultaneous eigenstate of $L^2$ and $L_z$. Thank you for comments and answer!